# Expanding a logical expression

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I need help understanding the following notation. I tried to expand it and that's where I realized I didn't quite get it. How do you expand the following: $${\underset{i=1}{\stackrel{3}{\bigwedge}}} {\underset{n=1}{\stackrel{3}{\bigwedge}}} {\underset{j=1}{\stackrel{3}{\bigvee}}}p(i,j,n)$$

I know that $\bigvee_{i=1}^{n} p_{i} = p_{1} \vee p_{2} \vee ... \vee p_{n}$ and the same for the logical conjunction $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n} p_n$ but I don't see how they would be combined correctly.

In the textbook I'm reading this notation is used in an example about satisfiability. This particular example is about Sudoku and the expression is the assertion that every row contains every number. I changed it from 9 to 3 so it's easier to show the expansion.

Comment: You can read it as $\bigwedge (\bigwedge (\bigvee p))$

Comment: You're dropping all of the subscripts. The innermost expression should be $$p(i,1,n)\vee p(i,2,n)\vee p(i,3,n)$$ and this gets repeated in the next level once for each value of $n$. Then *that* whole thing gets repeated for the outermost level for each value of $i$. Do you see?

Comment: Consider for simplicity the case with only $p(i,j)$ and unwind it from inside out : ${\underset{i=1}{\stackrel{3}{\bigwedge}}} {\underset{j=1}{\stackrel{3}{\bigvee}}}p(i,j)$ is : ${\underset{i=1}{\stackrel{3}{\bigwedge}}} (p(i,1) \lor p(i,2) \lor p(i,3))$ which in turn is : $[(p(1,1) \lor p(1,2) \lor p(1,3)) \land (p(2,1) \lor p(2,2) \lor p(2,3)) \land (p(3,1) \lor p(3,2) \lor p(3,3))]$

Comment: Thanks Mauro that makes it clear! Not sure how to accept your comment as an answer...